# I'm trying to insert two cells in a row of an HTML table

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to solve an exercise on the tables using only HTML. What I should get is this table: [image of the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0lPS.png) 
The main problem with my solution is that i can't insert the cells 'RAL' and 'Ore' under the cell 'Media'. So this is my table(incorrect): [image of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL8KP.png)

this is my code:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" width="30%">
<caption> Tabelle dipendenti </caption>
<thead>
    <tr> 
    
    <th colsrow="2" style="background-color:yellow;"> </th> <th colsrow="2">Distribuzione </th> 
        <th colspan="2"> Media </th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <th colspan="0" > </th> <th> </th>
        <th colspan="1">RAL </th> <th colspan="1" style="background-color:red;"> Ore </th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr> 
    
    <th style="background-color:yellow;"> Manager </th> <th> 2% </th> 
    <td>100.000 € </td> <td style="background-color:red;"> - </td>
    
    </tr>
    
    <tr> 
    
    <th style="background-color:yellow">Impiegati </th> <th> 20% </th>
    <td>40.000€ </td> <td rowspan="2" style="background-color:red;">  40 </td>
    
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    
    <th > Operai </th> <th> 78% </th> 
    <td> 35.000€ </td>
    
    </tr>
    
</thead>
</table>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with the number of total rows and columns of your table and try to split your table with a `thead` and `tbody`:

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" width="30%">
  <caption> Tabelle dipendenti </caption>
  <thead>
      <tr> 
        <th rowspan="2" style="background-color:yellow;"> </th>
        <th rowspan="2">Distribuzione </th> 
        <th colspan="2"> Media </th>

      </tr>    
      <tr>
          <th colspan="1">RAL </th>
          <th colspan="1" style="background-color:red;"> Ore </th>
      </tr>    
      <tr>     
        <th style="background-color:yellow;"> Manager </th>
        <th> 2% </th> 
        <td>100.000 € </td>
        <td style="background-color:red;"> - </td>    
      </tr>    
      <tr>     
        <th style="background-color:yellow">Impiegati </th>
        <th> 20% </th>
        <td>40.000€ </td>
        <td rowspan="2" style="background-color:red;">  40 </td>    
      </tr>    
      <tr>
        <th > Operai </th> <th> 78% </th> 
        <td> 35.000€ </td>    
      </tr>    
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" width="30%">
<caption> Tabelle dipendenti </caption>
<thead>
    <tr> 
    
    <th colsrow="2" rowspan="2" style="background-color:yellow;"> </th> <th colsrow="2" rowspan="2">Distribuzione </th> 
        <th colspan="2"> Media </th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
         
        <th colspan="1">RAL </th> <th colspan="1" style="background-color:red;"> Ore </th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr> 
    
    <th style="background-color:yellow;"> Manager </th> <th> 2% </th> 
    <td>100.000 € </td> <td style="background-color:red;"> - </td>
    
    </tr>
    
    <tr> 
    
    <th style="background-color:yellow">Impiegati </th> <th> 20% </th>
    <td>40.000€ </td> <td rowspan="2" style="background-color:red;">  40 </td>
    
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    
    <th > Operai </th> <th> 78% </th> 
    <td> 35.000€ </td>
    
    </tr>
    
</thead>
</table>
```

Changes made:
1.added `rowspan="2"` to first `th`
2.removed `<th colspan="0" > </th>`